# Background image doesn't display in CodeIgniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

My background image call by css

**css**

```
 background: url('../images/slider/download.jpeg') no-repeat 0 0!important;
```

and location like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ivory2\resources\images\slider
```

here the image does not take why?
IVORY2 is my project name

Comment: where is your css placed?

Comment: in here `C:\xampp\htdocs\ivory2\resources\images\slider`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\ivory2\resources\style1.css

Comment: @Nithinjustin Make sure your image has that name with that extension. The route seems to be correct.

Comment: thanks it works..but hover is not working.....rereadmore-btn:hover {
    background-position: 0 -186.5px;
}
.rereadmore-btn {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: -140px 0 0 0;
    background: url('images/slider/njn.png') no-repeat 0 0!important;  
   transition: .5s ease-out 0s;
    
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}

Comment: What's the location of the actual application?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\ivory2\application

Comment: image is showing..but hover transition effect not working

Comment: just a readmore button changes in z-index when hover

Comment: worked...thanks..just hv to call !important with styles